# Join and aggregate where date in right table <= date in left table

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, presto

Say I have one table that is has two columns - `customer_id` and `date`:

```
customer_id          date
          1    2020-01-29
          1    2020-03-14
          2    2020-04-05
          2    2020-02-18
```

I have another table that shows the date and amount that customers made a purchase on:

```
customer_id          date    amount
          1    2019-12-03        10
          1    2020-01-30        20
          1    2020-03-10        30
          1    2020-03-18        40
          2    2020-02-29        50 
          2    2020-03-10        60
          2    2020-04-01        70
```

I now want to do a join on the first table with second table that creates a new column showing the total aggregated sum of the purchase amounts to date on each row of the first table:

```
customer_id          date    amount_td
          1    2020-01-29           10
          1    2020-03-14           60
          2    2020-04-05          180
          2    2020-03-20          110
```

How can I do this? My initial idea of the logic would be something like:

```
SELECT
    table1.customer_id,
    table1.date,
    table2_agg as amount_td
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        SUM(amount)
    FROM
        table2
    HAVING
        table2.date <= table1.date
) table2_agg
ON
    table1.customer_id = table2_agg.customer_id
```

but of course this is syntactically and logically not quite there.

Comment: Not that bad. Your subquery needs a GROUP BY. And  HAVING should be WHERE. And the SUM() column needs a name.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, missed the group by when I was copying and pasting into here. I'm using Presto, but I hadn't even tried to run this thinking that I was quite a bit off with the logic

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the need to aggregate in `table2` based on the `date` from `table1`, this might be easier to write as a correlated subquery than a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    table1.customer_id,
    table1.date,
    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount 
              FROM table2
              WHERE table2.date <= table1.date AND
                    table2.customer_id = table1.customer_id), 0) AS amount
FROM
    table1
```

Alternatively you can write it as a `JOIN`, but the aggregation needs to occur at the top level of the query:

```
SELECT
    table1.customer_id,
    table1.date,
    COALESCE(SUM(table2.amount), 0) AS amount
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 ON table2.customer_id = table1.customer_id
          AND table2.date <= table1.date
GROUP BY table1.customer_id, table1.date
```

In either case the output is:

```
customer_id     date        amount
1               2020-01-29  10
1               2020-03-14  60
2               2020-04-05  180
2               2020-03-20  110
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4asLLA1FRAeXKa8c6NRKii/2)

Answer (score 0):

If your (undisclosed) DBMS supports lateral joins, you can do this:

```
select t1.*, t.amount
from table1 t1
  left join lateral (
     select t2.customer_id, sum(t2.amount) as amount
     from table2 t2
     where t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id
       and t2.date <= t1.date
     group by t2.customer_id
  ) as t on true
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ca66a508a07cf02a48c005f2949a95e3)